# Using repeat.for with bound number

Tags: aurelia

Consider sample below:

```
//edit.html
<input type="number" step="1" value.bind="number" />
<div repeat.for="num of number">${num}</div>

//edit.ts
export class Edit {
  number: number = 2;
}
```

I expect to see 2 divs on first page load and number of divs should change when I change number in input. Instead I get error

```
Value for 'number' is non-repeatable
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I figured it out. If you bind input field to variable, even when variable is number, it will be changed to string when changed by user. In my case, `number` became string once changed in input field. I used this gist to help me solve this problem:

https://gist.github.com/jdanyow/d9d8dd9df7be2dd2f59077bad3bfb399

It offers custom element and attribute for binding numbers to input fields.